# what is the meaning of dup('#') in assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm

e-g

1. source BYTE "This is the source string",0
2. target BYTE SIZEOF source DUP('#')

what is the function of Dup('#') in this lines of code.

Comment: Which MCU/MPU are you trying to write code on?

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h2ye0a0.aspx).

Comment: MASM Assembly language

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dup (#)` used for array declaration. For instance

```
array1  byte  20 DUP(0)      ;declare an array of 20 bytes
                             ;each byte initialized to 0
array2  byte  20 DUP('X')    ;declare an array of 20 bytes
                             ;each byte initialized to 'X'
array3  byte  20 DUP (?)     ;declare an array of 20 bytes
                             ;each byte is not initialized
```